# Why Angular HTTPClient repeat the rest call twice in this case?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, httpclient

I have an angular service that consume a Rest API but when I inspect the network and the backend I see that the API called twice every time :

This my Service code  :

```
getAllUsers():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(this.mainConfigService.getUsersUrl()).pipe(
        map(this.extractData));
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        return body || { };
}
```

In my component I called this service :

```
  getAllUser(){
    let users : User[] = [];
    this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data=>{
      this.usersList=data;
      data.forEach( (element) => {
        users.push(
               {
                fullName: element.fullName,
                firstName:element.firstName,
                lastName:element.lastName,
                mail:element.mail,
                idNumber:element.idNumber,
                accountExpiresDateTime:element.accountExpiresDateTime,
                role:element.role
             }
             );
      });
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    },err=>{
      this.handleError(err)
    })
  }
```

In the console I see that the API called twice even that the only place where I called the getAllUser() is in the Init Method

[image]

I still not able to find the cause of this problem

Comment: Can you provide a screen of the network tab, maybe it is OPTIONS method to conf client and server before request?

Comment: Yes it's an option method thanks !

Comment: The first request must be an OPTION. The second one is the true HTTP calls. Please visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably an OPTIONS request

> Preflighted requests
>
> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first send an HTTP OPTIONS request header to the resource on the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may have implications to user data. In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET or POST. Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
>   It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header such as X-PINGOTHER)

Comment: does it have any impact on page speed, like API call goes twice, so I want to understand if it slow down speed or any negative impact and if yes how can we avoid it.

I'm using Angular as frontend and laravel as Backend. Also using interceptors. Thanks!

Comment: No you can't avoid OPTIONS request, you can ignore them because every req is very tiny.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `HttpInterceptor` maybe that is doing it. In some cases that makes.